# Moving files in solaris - issue is /usr/bin/mv: arg list too long

Tags: solaris

I am trying to move audit files of total size 4.5 GB but getting error "Arg List Too Long"
can someone suggest a solution like some script etc. In my opinion one can use a loop where at each iteration a command will be constructed. plz guide

Regards

Comment: did you try `find dir1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t dir2`?

Answer (score 3):

See if this will do what you want:

From the man page of xargs from Solaris 8

Example 1: Using The xargs Command

```
 The following will move  all  files  from  directory  $1  to
 directory  $2,  and echo each move command just before doing
 it:

 ls $1 | xargs -I {} -t mv $1/{} $2/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can write a script with a for loop
2. you can use xargs as described above
3. you can mv manually alphabetically for instance, reducing the argument list

   mv a* targetdir
   mv b* targetdir

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
find $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco
ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017 | grep -c .jpg
ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco | grep -c .jpg
```

output to confirm:

```
(mds_env_gpu) brando9~/data/mds/mscoco $ find $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco
(mds_env_gpu) brando9~/data/mds/mscoco $ ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017 | grep -c .jpg
0
(mds_env_gpu) brando9~/data/mds/mscoco $ ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco | grep -c .jpg
118287
```

indeed that was the number of files:

```
(mds_env_gpu) brando9~/data/mds/mscoco $ ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017ls $MDS_DATA_PATH/mscoco/train2017 | grep -c .jpg
ls: cannot access '/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/data/mds/mscoco/train2017ls': No such file or directory

118287
```

The crux is that the `xargs` command will then invoke the `mv` command, passing the list of file names as arguments.